# Restore Binary Tree with PreOrder and InOrder - Javascript

Tags: javascript, binary-tree, inorder, preorder

Could somebody teach me how to restore a binary tree using Prorder and Inorder arrays. I've seen some examples (none in JavaScript) and they kind of make sense but the recursive call never returns a full tree when I try and write. Would love to see explanations as well. Here's some code to start off:

Creating a tree node uses this:

```
function Tree(x) { 
  this.value = x;
  this.left = null;
  this.right = null;
}
```

Creating the tree uses this:

```
function retoreBinaryTree(inorder, preorder) {

}
```

Some sample input:

```
inorder = [4,2,1,5,3]
preorder = [1,2,4,3,5,6]

inorder = [4,11,8,7,9,2,1,5,3,6]
preorder = [1,2,4,11,7,8,9,3,5,6]
```

**EDIT** I had been working on this for days and was unable to come up with a solution of my own so I searched some out (most were written in Java). I tried to mimic [this solution](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/construct-tree-from-given-inorder-and-preorder-traversal/) but to no avail.

Comment: I've tried to create a recursive function called build tree that took in the preorder and inorder list as well as varibles that stood for numbers like start, and end. The function would create a node, adjust start and end based on the index of the value of that node. Find left and right nodes if they exist, then return the node. Problem is it never returned a full tree. Here I'll post where I got that solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution in C++ which I think you could translate without problem:

```
/* keys are between l_p and r_p in the preorder array

   keys are between l_i and r_i in the inorder array
 */
Node * build_tree(int preorder[], long l_p, long r_p,
          int inorder[], long l_i, long r_i)
{
  if (l_p > r_p)
    return nullptr; // arrays sections are empty

  Node * root = new Node(preorder[l_p]); // root is first key in preorder
  if (r_p == l_p)
    return root; // the array section has only a node

  // search in the inorder array the position of the root
  int i = 0;
  for (int j = l_i; j <= r_i; ++j)
    if (inorder[j] == preorder[l_p])
      {
        i = j - l_i;
        break;
      }

  root->left = build_tree(preorder, l_p + 1, l_p + i, 
              inorder, l_i, l_i + (i - 1));
  root->right = build_tree(preorder, l_p + i + 1, r_p, 
               inorder, l_i + i + 1, r_i);

  return root;
}
```